# How to make a dynamic question answer form using formArray in angular 6

Tags: angular, formarray

I am trying to make a form which contains a question and some options for that as answers. Adding Options are dynamic, so I'm trying to implement it using formArray.
But at the same time, I need to save which option is correct, so for that, I'm using radio buttons with each option.

Problem is when I'm changing the radio button it doesn't uncheck previous ones.

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="questionForm">
  <button type="button" class="iconBtn" title="Add Options" (click)="addOptions()">
    Add Option
  </button>
  <div formArrayName="options">
    <div *ngFor="let option of questionForm.controls['options'].controls; let i = index">
        <div class="row" [formGroupName]='i'>
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-right">
                <span class="radio">
                    <label class="radio-inline" title="Select if this is correct answer">
                        <input type="radio" [formControlName]="'isCorrect'" value="1" (change)="selectCorrectOption($event)"/>
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option Text" [formControlName]="'optionText'"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript (ts):**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.questionForm = this._fb.group({
    'options': this._fb.array([
      this._fb.group({
        'isCorrect': [0],
        'optionText': ['']
      })
    ])
  });
}

public addOptions() {
  let control = < FormArray > this.questionForm.controls.options;
  control.push(this._fb.group({
        'isCorrect': [0],
        'optionText': ['']
      })
   );
}
```

Any Solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add name property in `<input type="radio">`

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your template code to have the same formControlName for every radio button like:

```html
<input type="radio" formControlName="isCorrect" value="1" />
<input type="radio" formControlName="isCorrect" value="0" />
<input type="radio" formControlName="isCorrect" value="0" />
```

and access the value via

```
questionForm.value.isCorrect
```

I found that adding the name attribute to the radio button tag is enough to meet the need of only having one button selected.

```html
<input type="radio" name="isCorrect" formControlName="isCorrect" (change)="selectCorrectOption($event)"/>
```